# powerBI azure client app permissions to other applications for report embedding

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

1. We created a PowerBI report and uploaded it to the SaaS cloud. PowerBI being a Microsoft product uses Azure for storage.
2. From our Java webapplication, we want to embed the report.
   PowerBI recommends the following steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app to achieve it.
3. We are not able to grant permissions for the “App” created in Azure.
   https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ApplicationsListBlade

It is basically failing to grant permission. I'm the owner of the "app" that I created, but my role in Azure is "user"...who would be able grant permission to my "app" that is looking for "Power BI" privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a user who has "Global administrator" directory role to do the "Grant Permissions".

It's stated in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app) you're following as well. The one you mention in point 2 of your question.

> PowerBI recommends the following steps
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app to
>   achieve it.

Here's screenshot of the relevant section. (Step 8)

[image]

Comment: @markchimail did it work out? Or did you face any issues?

Comment: In Azure AD I'm not able to contact the Global Admin associated to my Organization. There is no PIM access for me to assume the role. I'm trying to reach out my company's Office365  team...hoping that they would know about Azure Global admin role. We are a AWS Cloud shop and folks are surprised that there AD entries in Azure portal.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MarkChimail contacting your Office365 team seems logical because at least they have some cases to be aware of Azure AD. I don't know what you mean by "surprised that there are AD entries in Azure portal".. if you  mean you see some apps listed in Enterprise Applications, that can be simply because of O365 or even PowerBI or such services that your organization subscribes.. I don't know a good way to contact Global Admin, but you can always open up a new question right here on Stack Overflow for that and someone else might know the answer.. I'll try to find at my end too.. Good luck!